# Autorun.inf to disable autoplay

Tags: windows, autorun

So basically I have a usb drive, the goal is to disable the autoplay menu on any computer it is inserted into.

Is there any way to use a flag in the Autorun.inf to disable autoplay so the device can be connected without any user prompt.

It is difficult to find anything on Google in this regard because everything that comes up is to due with disabling it on your own PC.

Thanks.

Edit:
To clarify I am referring to the box windows opens to ask you what to do with the mass storage device. And just for this one specific drive, on any computer it gets connected to.

Comment: You can make the autorun launch a batch file, so you're really looking for some command lines.

Comment: When you say "autoplay menu," are you talking about the *dialog box* that Windows displays, asking the user whether to open Explorer, import photos, or do other actions based on the contents of the drive? Or is there an actual *menu* you're referring to? And when you want to disable it, do you mean just for the USB drive in question, or for all subsequent drives anyone might later insert into that computer, even after your drive has been removed? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite confident there is no way to do this on the device itself.

Microsoft mentions the following: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715

- you can edit the registry
- you can disable autorun through policy

I couldn't find anything specific from Apple, but similar to Windows, it doesn't appear to be possible.